# Como leer una linea en especifico de un archivo en C++?

Tags: c++, archivo

Hice una agenda donde me guarda datos en un archivo de texto.

Cuando encuentra el nombre de un contacto, quiero que me lea toda su información. Pero no tengo idea como leer solo una linea. Les agradezco cualquier ayuda, gracias. (Codigo en codeblocks)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct Persona
{
    char nombre[40];
    char direccion[40];
    double telefono;
    char email[40];
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anio;
};
typedef struct Persona contacto;

int main()
{
    contacto numero[100];
    int contador;
    char usuario[40];
    string buscador;
    cout<<"Cuantos contactos desea ingresar?";
    cin>>contador;
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i=0;i<contador;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del usuario: ";
        cin.getline(numero[i].nombre,40);
        cout<<"Ingrese la direccion: ";
        cin.getline(numero[i].direccion,40);
        cout<<"Ingrese telefono: ";
        cin>>numero[i].telefono;
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Ingrese el correo electronico: ";
        cin.getline(numero[i].email,40);
        cout<<"Ingrese dia, mes y anio: ";
        cin>>numero[i].dia;
        cin>>numero[i].mes;
        cin>>numero[i].anio;
        cin.ignore();
        ofstream agendita;
        agendita.open("agenda.txt",ios::binary|ios::app);
        agendita<<numero[i].nombre<<" "<<numero[i].direccion<<" "<<numero[i].telefono<<" "<<numero[i].email<<" "
        <<numero[i].dia<<"/"<<numero[i].mes<<"/"<<numero[i].anio<<"\r\n";
        agendita.close();
    }
    cout<<"A que persona desea buscar? ";
    cin>>buscador;

    ifstream buscar;
    buscar.open("agenda.txt");
    while(!buscar.eof())
    {
     buscar>>usuario;
    if (usuario==buscador)
    {
     cout<<usuario;
    }
    }
    buscar.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es que estas usando un archivo de texto plano, el cual debe leerse sí o sí de forma secuencial linea a linea. Para leer la linea 200, vas a tener que leer si o si las 199 lineas anteriores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Pregunta.

> Como leer una linea en especifico de un archivo en C++?

No se puede. Las líneas en un archivo de texto son, a grandes rasgos, aquello que hay entre un salto de línea (`\r\n`) y el siguiente... por lo que si necesitas saltar a una línea tendrás que leer línea a línea y contar cuántas llevas leídas. Eso no es práctico.

#### Alternativa.

Sin embargo estás de suerte porque tu estructura `Persona` es de tamaño homogéneo. Así que cada registro ocupa lo mismo en el archivo.

Por lo que veo también abres el archivo en modo binario (`agendita.open("agenda.txt",ios::binary|ios::app)`) así que si guardas los datos binariamente podrás [guardarlos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) y [leerlos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) en bloque:

```
// Guardo un registro
agendita.open("agenda.txt",ios::binary|ios::app);
agendita.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&numero[i]), sizeof(Persona));
agendita.close();
```

Así pues, si necesitas leer el contacto número [42](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu%C3%ADa_del_autoestopista_gal%C3%A1ctico_(libro)) harías lo siguiente:

```
// Leo el registro 42 (creo que es Arthur Dent).
ifstream agendita("agenda.txt", ios::binary);
agendita.seekg(42 * sizeof(Persona));
Persona p;
agendita.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p), sizeof(Persona));
```

#### ¿Buscar?.

Si no quieres escribir el archivo en formato binario y prefieres mantener el formato texto primero debes quitar el `ios::binary` de los parámetros del stream; después debes dejar de preocuparte de leer una línea específica ya que con tu *algoritmo* de búsqueda lo tienes "*ya solucionado*":

```
while(!buscar.eof())
{
    buscar>>usuario;
    if (usuario==buscador)
    {
        cout<<usuario;
    }
}
```

Una vez entras en el `if (usuario==buscador)` ya estás en el principio del registro así que ya puedes leer "*la línea en específico*" de los datos del registro. Pero ojo, ten en cuenta que  tu algoritmo de búsqueda falla si la dirección o email de un usuario coincide con el nombre de otro (tú sabrás si es esto posible o no).

Comment: Podrías plantear para la búsqueda un índice: lo incrementas en cada iteración y, sabiendo cuánto ocupa cada registro en el fichero (incluido salto de línea). Para ir de un registro al siguiente bastaría con hacer un seek a la posición que corresponda (index*tamaño de la estructura)... otra opción podría ser ignorar todos los caracteres siguientes hasta llegar al salto de línea (e ignorarlo también). Creo que serían opciones más limpias que la que planteas actualmente.

Comment: @eferion *bastaría con hacer un seek a la posición que corresponda (index x tamaño de la estructura)* eso es precisamente lo que hago en la sección *Alternativa* O_o

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo.    Ahora, estoy probando la Alternativa que @PaperBirdMaster indico. Me compila todo, no me da error y si me guarda los datos en el archivo. El problema es al leer un dato en ifstream, solo me saca del archivo, no se si funciona o no. ¿Cómo leo por consola esta función?

Comment: @JoséT. "*El problema es al leer un dato en ifstream, solo me saca del archivo*" no entiendo que quieres decir con esa frase.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Bien, para no confundir, hice lo que me indicaste `ifstream agendita("agenda.txt", ios::binary);
    string linea;
    agendita.seekg(1 * sizeof(Persona));
    Persona p;
    agendita.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p), sizeof(Persona));
    cout<<agendita.tellg()<<endl;
    getline(agendita,linea);
    cout<<linea;
    agendita.close();` Al momento de querer imprimir el primer contacto, me lee el numero 3.

Comment: ¿Para qué muestras `linea` después de leer en `p`? Los datos están ya leídos (en bloque) en `p`. ¿Qué contiene `p`?

Answer (score 2):

Buenos días, existe `fseek`, el cual te permite ir a una línea específica del archivo. [aquí](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) y [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm) te dejo información sobre esta función. además te dejo un [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Upf0x_LoSs) de youtube de como usarla.

Esta es la declaración de dicha función.

```
int fseek( std::FILE* stream, long offset, int origin );
```

El primer parámetro es el archivo (el stream que hayas abierto), el segundo es la posición (línea a la que quieras ir) y el tercero es el origen de donde se va a empezar a contar (pricipio del archivo, final del archivo)

Comment: Cabe señalar que `fseek` forma parte de la librería de IO de C adaptada a C++ en la cabecera `<cstdio.h>`. Por otro lado [José T](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21862/jos%c3%a9-t) está usando `fstream` no *file handlers*.