# ¿Cómo leer una línea en especifico de un archivo txt?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que, basado en un número aleatorio, seleccione la línea correspondiente a ese número y la imprima en pantalla. Cada línea tiene una longitud diferente y es lo que me está complicando.

O, en caso de no poderse de esta forma, ¿de qué otra forma podría hacerse?

Hasta ahora sólo tengo esto.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream archivo_entrada; 
    string linea;

    archivo_entrada.open("prueba.txt");    
    getline(archivo_entrada, linea);

    cout << linea << endl;
}
```

Comment: Listo, disculpa el mal formato, soy nuevo en este foro y no encontre otra forma de ponerlo

Comment: [relacionado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32275/como-leer-una-linea-en-especifico-de-un-archivo-en-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

Lo primero que hacemos es usar la funcion [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) dentro de un ciclo `while` que se ejecutara hasta que se termine de leer la ultima linea del archivo.

Dentro del ciclo `while`, iremos imprimiendo cada linea `cout << linea << endl`.

Y por ultimo, agregamos dos variables:

**contador** = Incrementa hasta que se llegue a la linea deseada

**max**    = Numero de linea deseado

Y cuando la variable `contador` sea igual a `total`, alli se imprime la linea.

En ese caso, si quieres que sea un numero aleatorio, o un numero de tu preferencia, solo debes reemplazar `cin >> max` -> (que es el ingreso de entrada por el teclado) por una asignacion e.j: `max = 10`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

        ifstream archivo_entrada("prueba.txt");;
        string linea;

        int contador = 0;
        int max;

        cout << "Escribe una linea: ";
        cin >> max;

        while(getline(archivo_entrada, linea)) {

                if(max == contador) {
                        cout << linea << endl;
                }

                contador++;
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**prueba.txt**

```
hola
esta
es
una
prueba
para
StackOverflow
En
Spanish
```

> Resultado

```
Ivan@ubuntu:tmp$ ./a.out 
Escribe una linea: 5
para
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero si era tan sencillo, por que cuando lo busque a algunos usuarios le decian que si en su archivo.txt todas las lineas no tenian la misma cantidad de caracteres no iba a funcionar?

Comment: @JustHalf No sabria decirtelo, pero en todo caso C++ tiene el tipo de dato `string` a diferencia de C es un poco mas "dinamico"

Comment: @JustHalf Si la pregunta te ha servido, recuerda marcarla como aceptada, para ayudar a futuros usuarios que busquen algo similar

Comment: Hecho! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

También lo puedes hacer con **seekg o fseek**

Posiciona el puntero en el byte que tu quieras del archivo, y así no tienes que leer todo el texto que habia antes de esa linea. El inconveniente es que debes saber en que byte empieza la linea. Pero si lo sabes te puede resolver el problema.

```
Ejemplo en C++
// read a file into memory
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    // get length of file:
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    // allocate memory:
    char * buffer = new char [length];

    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,length);

    is.close();

    // print content:
    std::cout.write (buffer,length);

    delete[] buffer;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Fuente:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

Ejemplo en C

```
/* fseek example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ( "example.txt" , "wb" );
  fputs ( "This is an apple." , pFile );
  fseek ( pFile , 9 , SEEK_SET );
  fputs ( " sam" , pFile );
  fclose ( pFile );
  return 0;
}
```

Fuente: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Cada linea termina en un byte que tiene este valor '\n'