# ¿como puedo leer una linea en especifico de un documento txt? c++

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un proyecto para una clase, se trata del juego del ahorcado, tengo las palabras con las que se va a jugar en un archivo txt, pero no se como leer una linea en especifico para poder sacar solo una palabra de todo el texto, hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
int menu = 0;
int numero;
int num=0;
char noman[100];
FILE* animales = fopen("animales.txt", "r");
if (animales == NULL) {
    printf("error");
}
printf("MENU DE OPCIONES\n 1.Nuevo Juego\n 2.Mejor Puntaje\n 3.Acerca De...\n 4.Salir\n");
scanf_s("%d", &menu);
int nscan = 0;

if (menu == 1) {
    num = 1 + rand() % (21 - 1);
    while (true) {
        nscan = fscanf(animales, "%15[^,], %d", noman, &numero);
        if (nscan == EOF)break;
        if (nscan != 2) printf("formato erroneo");      

    }
    system("pause");



    if (menu == 2) {


    }
    if (menu == 3) {


    }
    if (menu == 4) {



    }

    return 0;
}
      }
```

el archivo txt es asi:

> perro,1
>   gato,2
>   vaca,3
>   caballo,4
>   ardilla,5
>   pato,6
>   lobo,7
>   leon,8
>   tigre,9
>   oso,10
>   jirafa,11
>   mono,12
>   gorila,13
>   armadillo,14
>   paloma,15
>   aguila,16
>   serpiente,17
>   lagarto,18
>   cocodrilo,19
>   abeja,20

como puedo seguir?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como leer una linea en especifico de un archivo en C++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32275/como-leer-una-linea-en-especifico-de-un-archivo-en-c)

Answer (score 0):

> No se como leer una línea en especifico para poder sacar solo una palabra de todo el texto.
>
> […]
>
> El archivo txt es así:
>
> > perro,1 gato,2 vaca,3 caballo,4 ardilla,5 pato,6 lobo,7 leon,8 tigre,9 oso,10 jirafa,11 mono,12 gorila,13 armadillo,14 paloma,15 aguila,16 serpiente,17 lagarto,18 cocodrilo,19 abeja,20

No es lo mismo leer una línea que leer una palabra. Menos aún si además de la palabra hay un índice anexo, que implica leer el dato y post-procesarlo para quedarnos con la palabra.

Mi consejo es que, dado que quieres elegir una palabra al azar, leas todo el archivo y elijas una palabra de entre las leídas:

```
std::string palabra_aleatoria(std::string ruta_a_archivo)
{
    // Abrir archivo, sólo se entra en el if si el archivo se pudo abrir.
    if (std::ifstream archivo{ruta_a_archivo})
    {
        std::vector<std::string> palabras{};
        std::string palabra{};

        // Leer todo el contenido del archivo separando por espacios,
        // guarda cada parte leída en la variable 'palabra',
        // cuando no queda contenido por leer, el while se acaba.
        while (std::getline(archivo, palabra, ' '))
        {
            // Guarda cada palabra leída en el vector de palabras.
            palabras.push_back(palabra);
        }

        // Seleccionamos una palabra aleatoria de entre todas las leídas.
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, palabras.size());
        palabra = palabras[dis(gen)];

        // Devolvemos la palabra quitando el número anexo a la misma.
        return palabra.substr(0, palabra.find(','));
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No se pudo abrir " << ruta_a_archivo << '\n';

    return {};
}
```

Puedes usar el código anterior así:

```
int main()
{
    auto palabra = palabra_aleatoria("animales.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVPtjtowEPydPMWK/kgiuYjAfXFHeYS@QFuhje0EXxNv5Di0KuLZ6TokHOh@emY8M17bsm2/VlKez1@MlXWvNGwMdd5pbLbxB1Z@hhgxtrpFDlp6creIQ6uId8UHMgoUekyz@BhHpoS08@r1lUZjoOOsnPu/fnbK4ogVEcFmA7NWO0cihwo9iSUcUKJYgcQC65rEA6BTpq5RPEIbFE9QU0HiGWpNVryAN5XTYg3UsckC3o3DEkWeQ0OWkSVU5Axvz1fs1GDwYviBzWpqGH4ErPpB8ASddq3R1muRsz9W6DgwfwFJkhS78GINWOh3FMvF7C2OTvEpjodTXkYVXLFwuMNac1lnML1lXe@Z2qGTe3Og@zGZaUwje7wXTzMbtJdb2NxYb6fk7nh6m2T3nQLBzJ@9qfWYWWlfG6vTMUNMUgEJJBknDpHRZD1v@26/K1D@TkcoC1mneAq8vIWd0gcjNTh1bdL4fL1ePUOlbepUmmVXpremJNfsjPU7ZULjoveG7GYLvEwX107dvDP/9LA1vlaCb1f6R5Czf/YreDvte2cnct71BVvfuM1LY1WaiGSocoojXXd66iSp98PT/E78JKDtFfGtO@NgFuD7iwlI8tMmodaYGibNQ@EjQYPGXv7D5Wdw2F3E5/cy/pGgHO0W7HY@/wc)</kbd>.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Etiquetas tu pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) peo programas como si fuera [c](/questions/tagged/c):

- La cabecera `<iostream>` es exclusiva de C++ e incompatible con C.
- Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<ctype.h>` y `<string.h>` son exclusivas de C y aunque suelen ser compatibles con C++ no deben ser usadas en C++. Si necesitases usarlas (que no es el caso) deberías [usar la versión adaptada a C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742).
- La cabecera `<iostream>` ofrece flujos de datos conectados a la consola (`std::cin` y `std::cout`) y la cabecera `<stdio.h>` ofrece funciones de C para comunicarse con la consola; ambas cabeceras cumplen el mismo objetivo pero sólo necesitas una: la de C++.
- Las funciones `printf`, `scanf_s` y `fscanf` pertenecen a las utilidades de C, usa `std::cout`, `std::cin` y `std::ofstream` en su lugar.
- `FILE` es una utilidad de C, en C++ se usan los flujos de lectura de archivo `std::ofstream` y `std::ifstream`.
- `rand` es una [utilidad imprecisa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108985/2742) que no deberías usar pues es de C. Usa la cabecera `<random>` de C++.